# What could be causing the memory leak in my paint method?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, paint

As I usually do when I make a game in Java, I create an object to handle the graphics. But, never before have I had a memory leak somewhere inside the "main" paint method. It's never happened before, so I don't know what it could be. ***My guess*** is it has something to do with the Images/retrieving the images, because **if I wipe the cache clean and reload them each time, it doesn't appear to leak memory**. Any ideas?

Question: What could be the cause of a memory leak in the following:

***[Edit] It turns out it actually was the Fonts. Thanks.***

Paint method for reference:

```
public void drawFrame(Graphics2D g) {
    // Dimension screen = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    int width = CLIENT.GAMEFRAME.getBounds().width;
    int height = CLIENT.GAMEFRAME.getBounds().height;
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    Font font1 = null;
    Font font2 = null;
    try {
        font1 = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File(
                "./cache/fonts/Minecraftia.ttf"));
        font2 = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File(
                "./cache/fonts/SF Automaton Extended.ttf"));
        g.setFont(font1.deriveFont(15f).deriveFont(Font.BOLD));
    } catch (FontFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (CLIENT.user.loggedIn) {
        g.drawImage(images.getPermaImage(3), width - 520, height - 94, null);
        g.drawImage(images.getPermaImage(2), width - 518, height - 92, null);
        // Skills
        g.drawImage(images.getPermaImage(0), width - 516, height - 90, null);
        g.drawImage(images.getPermaImage(0), width - 466, height - 90, null);
        g.drawImage(images.getPermaImage(0), width - 416, height - 90, null);
        g.drawImage(images.getPermaImage(0), width - 366, height - 90, null);
        g.drawImage(images.getPermaImage(0), width - 316, height - 90, null);
        g.drawImage(images.getPermaImage(0), width - 266, height - 90, null);
        g.drawImage(images.getPermaImage(0), width - 216, height - 90, null);
        g.drawImage(images.getPermaImage(0), width - 166, height - 90, null);
        g.drawImage(images.getPermaImage(0), width - 116, height - 90, null);
        g.drawImage(images.getPermaImage(0), width - 66, height - 90, null);
        g.drawImage(images.getPermaImage(4), 0, height - 290, null);
        g.drawString(CLIENT.user.name + ": " + CLIENT.user.message, 8,
                height - 48);
    } else {
        g.drawImage(
                images.getPermaImage(5),
                (this.getWidth() - images.getPermaImage(5).getWidth(null)) / 2,
                (this.getHeight() - images.getPermaImage(5).getHeight(null)) / 2,
                null);
        g.drawImage(images.getPermaImage(7), ((this.getWidth() - images
                .getPermaImage(7).getWidth(null)) / 2) + 136,
                ((this.getHeight() - images.getPermaImage(7)
                        .getHeight(null)) / 2) - 106, null);
        if (!CLIENT.box1Active) {
            g.drawImage(
                    images.getPermaImage(6),
                    ((this.getWidth() - images.getPermaImage(6).getWidth(
                            null)) / 2) - 80,
                    ((this.getHeight() - images.getPermaImage(6).getHeight(
                            null)) / 2) - 106, null);
        } else {
            g.drawImage(
                    images.getPermaImage(9),
                    ((this.getWidth() - images.getPermaImage(6).getWidth(
                            null)) / 2) - 80,
                    ((this.getHeight() - images.getPermaImage(6).getHeight(
                            null)) / 2) - 106, null);
        }
        if (!CLIENT.box2Active) {
            g.drawImage(
                    images.getPermaImage(6),
                    ((this.getWidth() - images.getPermaImage(6).getWidth(
                            null)) / 2) - 80,
                    ((this.getHeight() - images.getPermaImage(6).getHeight(
                            null)) / 2) - 50, null);
        } else {
            g.drawImage(
                    images.getPermaImage(9),
                    ((this.getWidth() - images.getPermaImage(6).getWidth(
                            null)) / 2) - 80,
                    ((this.getHeight() - images.getPermaImage(6).getHeight(
                            null)) / 2) - 50, null);
        }

        g.drawImage(
                images.getPermaImage(11),
                ((this.getWidth() - images.getPermaImage(10).getWidth(null)) / 2) + 180,
                ((this.getHeight() - images.getPermaImage(10).getHeight(
                        null)) / 2) - 50, null);
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.setFont(font2.deriveFont(18f));
        g.drawString("LOG-IN", ((this.getWidth() - images.getPermaImage(10)
                .getWidth(null)) / 2) + 205, ((this.getHeight() - images
                .getPermaImage(10).getHeight(null)) / 2) - 18);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.setFont(font1.deriveFont(30f).deriveFont(Font.BOLD));
        g.drawString(
                CLIENT.user.usernameBox,
                ((this.getWidth() - (CLIENT.user.usernameBox.length() * 1)) / 2) - 225,
                ((this.getHeight()) / 2) - 95);
        g.drawString(
                CLIENT.user.passwordBox,
                ((this.getWidth() - (CLIENT.user.usernameBox.length() * 1)) / 2) - 225,
                ((this.getHeight()) / 2) - 39);
        if (CLIENT.user.rememberMe) {
            g.drawImage(
                    images.getPermaImage(8),
                    ((this.getWidth() - images.getPermaImage(8).getWidth(
                            null)) / 2) + 140,
                    ((this.getHeight() - images.getPermaImage(8).getHeight(
                            null)) / 2) - 110, null);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the ImageCache object:

```
public final class ImageCache {

public ArrayList<BufferedImage> images = new ArrayList<BufferedImage>();
public ArrayList<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<Integer>();
public ArrayList<BufferedImage> permanentImages = new ArrayList<BufferedImage>();
public ArrayList<Integer> pids = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public void loadImage(String path, int id) {
    try {
        images.add(ImageIO.read(new File(path)));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
    ids.add(id);
}

public void writeCache() {
    String path = "./cache/sprites/gameframe/";
    File f = new File(path);
    byte[] b;
    String zipFile = "./Cache.dat";
    FileOutputStream fout = null;
    try {
        fout = new FileOutputStream(zipFile);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ZipOutputStream zout = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(
            fout));

    File[] s = f.listFiles();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        b = new byte[2028];
        FileInputStream fin = null;
        try {
            fin = new FileInputStream(s[i]);
            zout.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(s[i].getName()));
            int length;
            while ((length = fin.read(b, 0, 1024)) > 0) {
                zout.write(b, 0, length);
            }
            zout.closeEntry();
            fin.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    try {
        zout.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void clearCache() {
    images.clear();
    ids.clear();
}

public void loadPermanentImage(String path, int id) {
    try {
        permanentImages.add(ImageIO.read(new File(path)));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
    pids.add(id);
}

public BufferedImage getImage(int id) {
    for (int i = 0; i < ids.size(); i++) {
        if (ids.get(i) == id) {
            return images.get(i);
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public BufferedImage getPermaImage(int id) {
    for (int i = 0; i < pids.size(); i++) {
        if (pids.get(i) == id) {
            return permanentImages.get(i);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you loading the fonts from file every `paint`? Maybe you should do that once on start..

Comment: While that's a good idea, I'm pretty sure it's not the leak. As I said, clearing the image cache each time eliminated the leak, but if I cleared the cache each time, it would be much slower and less efficient.

Comment: I'm not sure it's "the" leak, but it might be "a" leak.

Comment: The images should be cached. They should not be read in the painting method.

Comment: Do I actually keep re-reading the images each time? As far as I could tell, they were loaded into the cache, then retrieved using the ID they were assigned.

Comment: `Do I actually keep re-reading the images each time?` - Sorry, I thought I saw a comment that suggested you should get rid of the cache and load the images each time. That should not be done. Your current painting method only accesses the images from the cache which is the proper way to do it. I do not see how this will cause a memory leak, hence my suggestion to concentrate on the continual reading of the Font files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know if it will cause a memory leak or not but you should NOT be doing any file I/O in any painting method.

So you should NOT be reading the Font files every time the method is called.

Comment: I can't see how this is an answer. Shouldn't this be in the comments?

Comment: It's not the leak (as far as I could tell), and I know it's a bad idea to keep doing that. I haven't gotten around to optimizing the graphics part yet, I wanna finish it first before I tinker with that stuff. I just needed a quick way to test fonts and sizes, etc.

Comment: Actually it is the leak (Just tested). It doesn't make sense why clearing the image cache each time would fix it, but whatever. I let it run for a few minutes, and it stuck around 100MB, so I guess it was actually the solution, thanks.